# Is it okay to put markers or queues in info.plist for sake of clarity when editing?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, info.plist

Within iOS or OS X apps, is it okay to put stuff in the plist?

For easy copy and paste between similar, but not identical plists, I've done like this:

[image]

Is it okay? Or will there be any problems?

I'm specifically thinking about the `------- Shared between plists --------`

Comment: it is ok, depending on what you want to store. You should not store credentials to servers, user's credentials and about any private data ...

Comment: In plists, yes, in `Info-YourApp.plist`, I would say No.  It's there for a purpose and not for general storage.

Answer (score 3):

The root object of most plist files and especially the Info.plist is a dictionary. Order of elements within dictionaries is not defined, so marking a region of keys like you did can not work reliably.

There's probably a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish. Info.plist files can be preprocessed using cpp.

Comment: Okay. I've filed a different question based on your suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256338/shared-info-plist-between-several-targets-using-gcc-preprocessor-macros-for-main

Answer (score 0):

info-plist is kinda initialiser of application which try to define the attributes to application on purpose and just for your sake its not a good idea and i could be readable by user easily.