# Shared info.plist between several targets using GCC preprocessor macros for maintaining specific fields

Tags: xcode, info.plist

In many of my apps I have 3 different build configurations (debug, release, sandbox). One experiences this is needed needed when working with different environments and in app purchase.

Often there are only small changes like `CFBundleIdentifier`. Is it possible to use GCC preprocessor macros for keeping the variation within different build configurations and at the same time only use one plist?

Answer (score 2):

For simple changes it is often not even necessary to use the C preprocessor. In these cases it is often sufficient to define a custom build setting and use the value of this setting in the Info.plist file. Build settings are expanded in Info.plist by default.

**Example:**

In Xcode in the project view select "Build Settings" and use the + button to add a "User-Defined Setting". Name the setting for example `MY_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and type a value, for example `MyApp.agens.no`.

The open the Info.plist file, select the "Bundle identifier" key and set its value to `${MY_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`.

If you change the `MY_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` build setting in another configuration or target, the product will be built using the new bundle identifier.